# Animate div position when other content size changes

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a content div, and another div that goes underneath the first. The first div's content changes dynamically, and its height changes as necessary. Normally, the second div's position automatically gets bumped up and down as the height of the first div changes. How can I animate the movement of the second div, preferably using just CSS and JS (no jQuery)?

Here's a visual:
[image]

On the left are my two divs, initially. Sometimes, div1 will expand in height to fit its contents, and div2 is pushed down. How can I animate the movement of div2?

Comment: Only CSS is very difficult...

Comment: Dhaivat is right. You want your footer to animate to the bottom of the content div, but without using JS, it might not be possible.

Comment: Dhaivat Pandya, DanRedux: the OP asked for at least CSS & JS

Comment: I'm comfortable with CSS and JS. I'm not familiar with jQuery and not comfortable with its syntax, but if someone can provide clear sample code I'll take jQuery.

Comment: Attempting successful cross browser animation without a js library is like asking for a glass of water without the glass...

Comment: IE users can be left with the jumping; I'm okay with the animation being WebKit only.

Comment: I think I'm just not reading the question correctly, but how do you want to animate the second div?  Just go up and down as the first div does? or something else?

Comment: @Stanley, I've added a visual. Yes, I'd like it to go up and down as the content height of the first div changes.

Comment: As I can see from your image (bot not from your Q) I see you want both divs to 'scale' with animation. right?

Comment: No, first div doesn't have to scale smoothly (I fade it in and out when updating content. Works fine). I want to move the second div, not scale it.

Comment: @Inspire48: do you have read my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://jsbin.com/uwoxek

```
function init() {
    var header = document.getElementById('header');
    var header_height = header.offsetHeight;
    header.style.height = '10px';
    header.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    var i = 0;
    var animation = setInterval(function () {
        if (i <= header_height) {
            header.style.height = (10 + i) + 'px';
        } else {
            clearInterval(animation);
            header.style.overflow = 'block';
        }
        i++;
    }, 10); 
}
```

ok, maybe some note are required?
what you have to move is not the "second" div, but the "first", that by moving will automatically push the second at the bottom ( or end of the first ) hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xS3y7/

```
#div1 {
    width: 50px; // Parent div needs width and height for this to work.
    height: 50px;
    background-color : red;
    position: relative;
}

#div2 {
    position: absolute;  //positioning based on parent.
    width: 100%; // 100% width of parent
    height: 20%; // 20% width of parent
    background-color: blue;
    bottom: 0px; // Place on the bottom
}​
```

The important thing to note is that the parent `<div>` must have either *absolute* or *relative* positioning, and the child `<div>` must have absolute positioning.  Absolute positioning bases its positioning off its nearest parent element (in this case, `#div1`).  Absolute positioning gives us the ability to place our element anywhere we want (in relation to the parent element), calculate values off, so this is really powerful.

For a good read up, check out Chris Coyier on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).